# Get data from XML string in VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm having an XML sting looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SR Workstation="0014" Status="Active">
 <OS>
  <Identification Hardware="DELL" SerialNumber="123456789">Confirmed</Identification>
  <CN> EXTERN</CN>
  <CV>1.1.2.45</CV>
  <TS>Idle</TS>
  <TSS>Ok</TSS>
  <ReaderStatus Reader="Icc">Enabled</ReaderStatus>
  <ReaderStatus Reader="MS">Enabled</ReaderStatus>
  <LPS>Unavailable</LPS>
 </OS>
</SR>
```

I can get the Workstation data and the Status Data with this script in VB.net

```
Dim sr As New System.IO.StringReader(l_Result.XMLData)
        Dim doc As New Xml.XmlDocument
        doc.Load(sr)
        Dim reader As New Xml.XmlNodeReader(doc)
        While reader.Read()
            Select Case reader.NodeType
                Case Xml.XmlNodeType.Element
                    If reader.Name = "SR" Then
                        If reader.GetAttribute("WorkStation") = "0014" Then
                            txtStatus.Text = reader.GetAttribute("Status")
                            txtSerial.Text = reader.GetAttribute("Identification/SerialNumber")
                            txtHardware.Text = reader.GetAttribute("Identification/Hardware")
                            lblConfirmed.Text = reader.GetAttribute("Identification")
                        End If
                    End If

            End Select
        End While
```

But getting the values 123456789 (SerialNumber), DELL (Hardware) and Confirmed  isn't working.

Can someone help me?  I aint getting errors but my textboxes and label remain empty.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `XmlNodeReader` (I much prefer `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`) but I have a feeling you cannot attempt to traverse to a child node's attribute that way. Or, if you can, you would need to include "OS" in the path to "Identification".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [VB.Net XML Axis Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/xml-axis/xml-axis-properties):

```
Dim x = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(l_Result.XMLData), e = x...<Identification>
txtStatus.Text = x.@Status
txtSerial.Text = e.@SerialNumber
txtHardware.Text = e.@Hardware
lblConfirmed.Text = e.Value
```

To loop over elements:

```
For Each e In x...<ReaderStatus>
    Debug.Print(e.Value)
    Debug.Print(e.@Reader)
Next
```

Comment: Hey @Slai ,  This is working,   But i have more then one ReaderStatus,  how can i perform a while or for each loop ??

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Linq to XML. Then your code is easy:

```
Dim doc = XDocument.Parse(l_Result.XMLData)

txtStatus.Text = doc.Root.Attribute("Status").Value
txtSerial.Text = doc.Root.Element("OS").Element("Identification").Attribute("SerialNumber").Value
txtHardware.Text = doc.Root.Element("OS").Element("Identification").Attribute("Hardware").Value
lblConfirmed.Text = doc.Root.Element("OS").Element("Identification").Value
```

Comment: Still nothing is happening

Comment: @ThomasDutoit - Please post your actual XML then. I tested against your sample - assuming it had at least one enclosing node - and it worked just fine for me.

Comment: @ThomasDutoit - Is there an XML namespace defined?

Comment: @ThomasDutoit - I updated my code to suit your real XML. Tested and working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xml linq to get descendants :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As New Xml.XmlDocument
        doc.Load(sr)
        Dim reader As New Xml.XmlNodeReader(doc)
        While Not reader.EOF
            If reader.Name <> "SR" Then
                reader.ReadToFollowing("SR")
            End If
            If Not reader.EOF Then
                Dim sr As XElement = XElement.ReadFrom(reader)
                If CType(sr.Attribute("WorkStation"), String) = "0014" Then
                    txtStatus.Text = reader.GetAttribute("Status")

                    txtSerial.Text = CType(sr.Descendants("SerialNumber").FirstOrDefault(), String)
                    txtHardware.Text = CType(sr.Descendants("Hardware").FirstOrDefault(), String)
                    lblConfirmed.Text = CType(sr.Descendants("Identification").FirstOrDefault(), String)

                    Exit While
                End If
            End If
        End While

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: I changed From : Identification/Hardware To : Hardware

Comment: ok,   but it still says there is an error on    sr.Descendants

There is something wrong there. Didn't know that getting a XML value was this difficult

Comment: There could be a few things causing the error.  I changed the code to the way I always do these loops.  See if this solves the error.